# Should I use a home button in mobile PWA version next to the back arrow?

Tags: usability, navigation, back-button, pwa

I'm working on a PWA website. I'm currently working on the mobile version.
And as expected in PWA, I try to be as native as possible so I plan to use a back button on the top left of the screen whenever I go a level deeper.

But as it's still web and people can land on a product page directly from google, I feel like I should add the website's logo next to the back arrow.

And that's where it feels weird. We don't see that kind of thing in native apps so I'm wondering i that's a good idea.
What about the homepage? The logo should have the same position on all pages but I can't leave a gap on homepage since there is no back arrow.

**What do you guys think? Whould it feel weird the have the logo next to the back arrow?**
I'm not using a burger menu.

Edit: [Flipkart does that in their product page for instance](https://www.flipkart.com/zwart-rhomrov-mustard-32-l-backpack/p/itmeg76jzfrjrymb?pid=BKPEG76JPNEBZZXT).

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes, a logo next to an arrow is confusing. It would lead to the impression that it directs to an external website of sorts, not a homepage. Have you considered accompanying the back button with a label indicating where it will lead?

For example: landing on a product page. You can show a back button with the label: "to overview" or if there is no product overview page, simply "to homepage". I'd refrain from using the word 'back to' because as you said, you might enter through a search engine and this would be a bad descriptor.

Comment: Actually, there is the title of the page in the middle. I don't think I'll have enought place to add "to homepage" or "to categories". What do you think of Flipkart exemple tat I've added in the main post?